# Excel Wizards - using VLOOKUP to find and copy cells, "best fit" search issues

Tags: vba, excel, multiple-columns, copy-paste, vlookup

I am using this formula as my base:

=VLOOKUP(B1, E$1:F$13728, 2, FALSE)

Then I'm copying the formula down, so I get B2, B3 etc.

I have a problem in that the names in my B column are not exact matches to those in my searched range. However, they contain much of the same things, "limited", "ltd", "financial" etc. This means that swapping FALSE for TRUE means I end up pulling all kinds of random data.

What would be the best way to pull the data relevant to the 'best fit' from the range?

Your help would be most appreciated, and I'm sure would allow for ease of use of such formula for many such excel failures as myself.

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1

Comment: Maybe a fuzzy match:  http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/hall-fame-winners/69649-alans-udfs-fuzzy-match-problem.html

Answer (score 1):

I have found it easier to use INDEX(MATCH()) to accomplish this, rather than V-LOOKUP.

For a simple example, I have 2 sheets in my workbook with only 2 columns each.

Sheet: testData

[image]

Sheet: testData2

[image]

I want to check if the [Name] exists in Sheet testData2, and if it does, return the value of [TestValue] and insert into [Column1] on Sheet testData1. It sounds like that is what you want.

Here is what the formula would look like with INDEX(MATCH())

```
=INDEX(testData2!B:B,MATCH([@Name],testData2!A:A,0))
```

INDEX returns a value from an array based on row and column numbers provided, this gives us the values we want from [TestValue]

MATCH searches for the value and returns the relative position, allowing us to match the correct row from [TestValue].

If you need further explanation, please have a read [here](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/08/13/excel-index-match-function-vlookup/). They do a better job explaining the use of INDEX(MATCH()) and the advantages it has over V-LOOKUP.

Answer (score 0):

As a "VBA" solution, place the following code in any module code pane of the workbook both "Sheet1" and " Sheet2"  sheets belong to:

```
Sub FillColumn2()

Dim rngToSearchIn as Range, rngToSearchFrom as Range, found as Range, cell as Range 

Set rngToSearchFrom = GetColumnUsedRange(Sheets("Sheet1"), "A")
Set rngToSearchIn  = GetColumnUsedRange(Sheets("Sheet2"), "X")

For Each cell In rngToSearchFrom 
   Set found = rngToSearchIn.Find (What:=cell.Value, LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues, MatchCase=True)    
   If Not found is Nothing then cell.Offset (,1) = found.Offset (,1)
Next cell

End Sub 


Private Function GetColumnUsedRange (sht as Worksheet, col as string)

With sht    
  Set GetColumnUsedRange = .Range(.Cells (1,col), .Cells(Rows.Count,col).End (xlUp))    
End With

End Function
```

Now you can call it from Excel by either placing a button on the sheet you want to "update" and attach it to the "FillColumn2" Sub or clicking the "Macro" button and selecting the "FillColumn2" sub from the dropdown menu that appears